# Is there a way to get the total number of render components in a react application?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react JS application with Redux, and I would like to know the amount of components that are rendered at any given tme, i.e. any component that is currently mounted in the React tree should be counted. is there any library/approach to get this?

Answer (score 0):

You can install redux add-on to your chrome browser . It will show you your components and it’s state.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd
After installation you’ll be able to track your components in your Chrome browser.

Comment: I do have redux dev tools, but how can I get the total number of components... I don't think this gives an answer